# UITextView textViewDidChange: does not recognize newline character

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios7

Trying to increase the size of a `UITextView` programmatically depending on what text has been inputted into it. The problem is, `textViewDidChange:` will only recognize new line characters if I input something after inputting them. For example, I'm trying to input the following:

Hi, my\n name is Jimmy.

This is what I'll get if I print this in NSLog in `textViewDidChange:`

```
Log: H
Log: Hi
Log: Hi,
Log: Hi, m
Log: Hi, my
Log: Hi, my (here goes the new line, but it's not recognized)
Log: Hi, my
 n (it's recognized on this line, only after something is inputted after it).
```

If I try to input two newlines, only the first one will be recognized and only after I input the second one. Is this some sort of a bug or am I missing something, is there a way to fix this? This used to work properly on iOS 6.

EDIT --
To clarify the problem a bit more, I do get notified that the text has been changed, the problem is the new text is an empty character instead of new line.

EDIT --
It seems that currently the only proper way to find the fitting size for UITextView is by using its `sizeThatFits:` method while passing it the bounding size. Also if you're changing `UITextView`'s proportions programmatically, it would be wise to remove any autoresizing masks from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me on both iOS 6 and iOS 7. Keep in mind that NSLog will sometimes not show new lines at the end of log like you would expect, so try to log something else after `textView.text`, for example:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"TextView text changed to: \"%@\"", textView.text);
}
```

If it really doesn't log new lines, then it does sound like a bug that you should [report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Dammit! True, the problem is with the `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` method then.

Comment: Yep, just tried this myself, that method will not return an increased frame if the line of it is empty. Not sure if this is a bug or feature, but it can't hurt to try reporting it as a bug.